# merging pdf and preserve SetTagged

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp 5.x. I'm trying to merge two pdfs and preserve the isTagged flag. When I remove copy.SetTagged(); the result pdf contains both pdfs which is great. When adding the copy.SetTagged() is get an exception

```
Exception -->System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
at System.IO.FileStream.get_Position()
```

Here is the code

```
List<string> filesToMerge = new List<string> { "C:/dev/dcs/wp-cla-dcs/Hex/Docs/metadata/coverPage.pdf", "C:/dev/dcs/wp-cla-dcs/Hex/Docs/metadata/49W7a.pdf" };
string outputFileName = "C:/dev/dcs/wp-cla-dcs/Hex/Docs/metadata/results.pdf";

using (FileStream outFS = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create))
using (Document document = new Document())
//  using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, outFS))
using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outFS))
{
    {
        copy.SetTagged();
        // Set up the iTextSharp document
        document.Open();
        foreach (string pdfFile in filesToMerge)
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile))
            {
                copy.AddDocument(reader);
                copy.FreeReader(reader);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Structure in PDF is very important for us (us being iText Group), especially since so many companies needs compliance with PDF/UA, but the original architecture of iText predates PDF/UA (and even Tagged PDF). For a long time, we tried not to touch that architecture. New versions of iText weren't 100% compatible with previous versions, but an effort was done to keep new versions "as compatible as possible". However, over 15 years, we had hitting the limitations of the original architecture on many occasions.

Comment: And that's why we decided to rewrite iText from scratch, resulting in iText 7, a version that completely breaks compatibility with previous iText versions. Structure in PDF (Tagged PDF and PDF/UA) was one of the reasons for making that decision. It just wasn't possible to continue development in that area while keeping the old architecture. This is a long answer to explain that what you need can't be done with iText 5. You need iText 7 for that.

Answer (score 0):

despite @bruno-lowagie's comment, I have had better results doing this with with iText5.

Uisng iText7, `PdfMerger` left several  contents untagged (all were tagged in the source document). `PdfCopy` in iText5 however worked just fine, only needed to manually add Xmp metadata, title, lang, etc:

```cs
public static void CombineMultiplePDFs(string[] fileNames, string outFile)
{
    var lang = "en";
    var title = "My new title";

    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    Document document = new Document();

    // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
    FileStream newFileStream = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create);
    PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, newFileStream);

    writer.SetTagged();

    writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7;
    writer.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.DISPLAYDOCTITLE, new PdfBoolean(true));
    writer.Info.Put(PdfName.TITLE, new PdfString(title));
    writer.CreateXmpMetadata();

    // step 3: we open the document
    document.Open();

    // set meta data
    document.AddLanguage(lang);
    document.AddTitle(title);

    // keep an array of all open readers so they can be closed again.
    var readers = new PdfReader[fileNames.Length];
    for (var fi = 0; fi < fileNames.Length; fi++)
    {
        // we create a reader for a certain document
        var fileName = fileNames[0];
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
        readers[fi] = reader;
        reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();

        // step 4: we add content
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            // IMPORTANT: the third param is is "KeepTaggedPdfStructure"
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i, true);
            writer.AddPage(page);
        }
    }

    // step 5: we close the document and writer
    writer.Close();
    document.Close();

    // close readers only after document is lcosed
    foreach (var r in readers)
    {
        r.Close();
    }
}
```